# Function Where f_y Exists Nowhere

Tags: calculus, functions

Find a function $f=f(x,y)$ such that $f_{xy}$ exists for all $(x,y),$ but $f_y$ exists nowhere.

I think $f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: For that $f$, $f_y$ exists everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

No, that function doesn't work at all: $f_y$ exists everywhere where $f$ is defined, after all.

---

For a different approach, consider something like this: Take your favorite nowhere differentiable function $g$ and define $f(x, y) = g(y)$. Then $f_y$ doesn't exist anywhere; what is $f_x$, and hence $f_{xy}$?

Comment: So something like f(x,y)=y^2? But how does that prove f_y exists nowhere?

Comment: No. Is the function $y^2$ nowhere differentiable?

Comment: It's differentiable everywhere. So I guess something like f(x,y)=x/(x^2+y^2) since there's a point (0,0) that doesn't exist?

Comment: Nice example under "For a different approach ..."   +1

Comment: @Holly Again no: The key point is that you need a function which is *never* differentiable. Guessing various polynomials and rational functions won't work, since they're usually differentiable.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks! ${}$

Comment: @T.Bongers My pleasure!

Comment: Every function I can think of is differentiable. Could I have a hint? Maybe a square-root function? @T.Bongers

Comment: @Holly Again no: that's differentiable at most points. Try thinking of a function that's not even continuous anywhere.

Comment: I'm honestly out of ideas. Only thing I can think of is a piecewise function. @T.Bongers

Comment: @Holly In that case, it's likely time to sit down with a real analysis textbook, and look up examples of nowhere continuous (or if you prefer, continuous but nowhere differentiable) functions; you can search around the site here and find many examples.

Comment: Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Holly I gave you quite a few, but if you're not at all familiar with discontinuous functions (or nowhere continuous functions), it's time to go and get the background in analysis. I'd suggest a book like Abbott's Understanding Analysis.

Comment: @T.Bongers I am. But I guess it's hard to think about functions where fy does not exist. Usually the functions I seen have this kind of condition.